# Use Array methods on Iterables

Tags: javascript, arrays, stream, iterable

I was wondering if there was a way / an easy way to use methods of the global JavaScript `Array` object, like `Array.prototype.map`, `Array.prototype.reduce` or even `Array.prototype.filter` on `Iterables` objects. Or at least, without needing to create a temporary array.

I've search all over on the Mozilla website, StackOverflow, Google, GitHub, etc... but didn't find anything answering my question.

---

Practical example:

Let's say I want to calculate the `sum` of all numbers from `1` to a certain number "`num`" (let's say `10`).

I was thinking of

1. using an `Iterator` / `Generator function` to get the numbers needed, one by one (`Generator` in my example below)
2. and then sum them up using a method like `Array.prototype.reduce()`.

This looks do-able for me, since these kind of methods (`reduce`) use one value at a time, then asking for the next one when the operation completed, pretty much like `Streams` in `Java`. And that's exactly what an `Iterable` does.

```js
mySum(10); // returns 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 = 55

/**
 * Sums all the number from 1 to the provided number
 * @param num {number} the maximum number to include in the sum
 * @returns the sum of all numbers from 1 to the provided number
 */
function mySum(num) {

    function* myGenerator() {
        for(let i = 1; i <= num; ++i) {
            yield i;
        }
    }

    return myGenerator().reduce((previous, current) => previous + current, 0);

}
```

This code above obviously doesn't work, since `Iterable`'s don't have a `reduce` method.
But why couldn't the iterators have one?

**Is there a way to avoid creating a temporary array like in the following?**

```js
mySum(10); // returns 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 = 55

/**
 * Sums all the number from 1 to the provided number
 * @param num {number} the maximum number to include in the sum
 * @returns the sum of all numbers from 1 to the provided number
 */
function mySum(num) {

    function* myGenerator() {
        for(let i = 1; i <= num; ++i) {
            yield i;
        }
    }

    return Array.from(myGenerator()).reduce((previous, current) => previous + current, 0); // notice here the change

}
```

Comment: You can sum it without `reduce`, but it seems like you want a solution that uses both a generator and reduce. Is that right? Could you write your own `reduce` method?

Comment: @ggorlen > you want a solution that uses both a generator and reduce. Is that right?
Yes, exactly. Wouldn't it be great to use some of the methods we use on arrays on iterators? I know I can sum numbers without `reduce`, but `reduce` seems generic enough to be applied to iterators too. I'll try writing a custom reduce function for iterators.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's the **best** way (my generator experience is limited) - but this way there's no temporary array

```js
function mySum(num) {

    function* myGenerator() {
        for(let i = 1; i <= num; ++i) {
            yield i;
        }
    }
    let sum = 0;
    for(let value of myGenerator()) {
      sum += value;
    }
    return sum;
}
console.log(mySum(10));
```